# ScrollMagic React

Tags: reactjs, scrollmagic

How I can do something like planet on this [link](https://www.translate-wf.com/) with help [ScrollMagic](https://github.com/bitworking/react-scrollmagic) in React?
My code

```
<div className={styles.containerMain}>
      <div>
        <Controller>
          <Scene duration={300} triggerElement="#first-container" offset={500}>
            {(progress) => (
              <Tween
                from={{
                  css: {
                    top: '0',
                  },
                  ease: 'Circ.easeOutExpo',
                }}
                to={{
                  css: {
                    top: '-500px',
                  },
                  ease: 'Circ.easeOutExpo',
                }}
                totalProgress={progress}
                paused
              >
                <div id="first-container" style={{ height: '100vh', position: 'relative' }}>
                  <div className={styles.container}>
                    <div  className={styles.contentContainer}>
                      <div className={styles.textSmall}>We</div>
                      <div className={styles.textLarge}>Deliver</div>
                      <div className={styles.containerText}>
                        <div className={styles.textSmall}>Quality</div>
                        <div className={styles.textSmall}>Software </div>
                      </div>
                      <div className={styles.textLarge}>Globally</div>
                      <div className={styles.globe}>
                        <Globe  /> //this is image svg
                      </div>
                     
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </Tween>
            )}
          </Scene>
      </Controller>
</div>
</div>
```

I need:
I see part of my image and than I am scrolling and I see full of my image (image replace text), than do something like in [link](https://www.translate-wf.com/)

Comment: Welcome on SO! Could you please provide us with some reproducible app where we can check what the actual issue is? A good place would be https://codesandbox.io/ Because right now it's hard to understand what issue you are actually facing.

Comment: GreenSock doesn't recommend ScrollMagic. Instead they recommend the official scroll plugin: [ScrollTrigger](https://greensock.com/scrolltrigger/)! It's better in every way.